# Threading decorator is not callable

Tags: python, multithreading

I am implementing a thread as a decorator to a class which should apply threads to the method, all concurrently. However, I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'TEST_THREAD' object is not callable

The example below should print out each iteration over the maximum thread number.

```
def start_workload(NUM_THREADS):
    def wrapper(fn, *args):
        thread = []
        for i in range(*args):
            t = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=(i,))
        #t = threading.Thread(target=do_query, args=(i,))
            t.start()
            thread.append(t)
        for i in range(*args):
            thread[i].join()
    return wrapper

class TEST_THREAD(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
        self._args = args
    @start_workload
    def print(self, threads):
        print(threads, self._args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = TEST_THREAD(*list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
    test.print(5)
```

I was expecting the wrapper to perform the same functionality like the following approach:

```
class TEST_THREAD:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
        self._args = args
    
    def print(self, threads):
        print(threads, self._args)

def start_workload(fn, num_thread):
    thread = []
    print(num_thread)
    for i in range(num_thread):
        t = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=(i,))
        t.start()
        thread.append(t)
    for i in range(num_thread):
        thread[i].join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = TEST_THREAD(*list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
    start_workload(test.print, 5)
```

Expected output:

```
0 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
1 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
2 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
3 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
4 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: You're passing the `TEST_THREAD` object that would otherwise be bound to `self` in `print` as `fn` in the wrapper function. Your wrapper has a completely different signature than the method it's replacing

Comment: You also never use `NUM_THREADS` (which is a confusing name for the decorated function) inside of `start_workload`

Comment: @Brian so its taking `TEST_THREAD` as opposed to `print` as the method? How do I make sure it is taking `print` as `fn`?

Comment: You'll need to re-write `start_workload` and its internal `wrapper` to work correctly with the arguments that they receive. Remember that the `@start_workload` syntax is just a shorthand for `print = start_workload(print)`. Think through how that function call evaluates, what function gets bound to `print` as a result, and how _that_ function will behave when its looked up as a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a decorator without parens `@start_workload def ...`, the function is used as the argument to the decorator function. So in this case you assigned `TEST_THREAD.print` as `NUM_THREADS` in `start_workload`.

This decorator then returns a function that takes two arguments. Because you are wrapping a class method, the first argument provided will be `self`, so calling `test.print(5)` is really calling `wrapper(fn, *args)` where `fn` is `self` and `*args` is `(5,)`.

You then end up passing fn (which is self, the instance of TEST_THREAD) to `threading.Thread(target=fn, args=(i,))`. This results in the error because it is using that instance as a callable to threading.

Its unclear exactly what you want to do here, but something like this is probably closer.

1. Don't use a parameterizable decorator, the number of threads is being passed through the function call as normal arguments.
2. You want to use the `threads` argument to be the total number of threads used. You also want to change the `threads` argument being passed to the method to be the index of the thread. This means we'll need to modify the arguments being proxied to the call to `threading.Thread`.
3. You're printing from multiple threads, so you probably want to use a method that wont have outputs being jumbled on top of eachother. The logging module would be good here.

```
import logging
import threading

def start_workload(fn):
    def wrapped(self, threads, *args, **kwargs):
        assert isinstance(threads, int)
        assert threads > 0

        ts = []
        for i in range(threads):
            new_args = (self, i, *args)
            t = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=new_args, kwargs=kwargs)
            t.start()
            ts.append(t)
        for t in ts:
            t.join()
    return wrapped

class TEST_THREAD(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
        self._args = args

    @start_workload
    def print(self, threads):
        logging.info(f"{threads}, {self._args}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    test = TEST_THREAD(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    test.print(5)
```

```
INFO:root:0, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
INFO:root:1, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
INFO:root:2, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
INFO:root:3, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
INFO:root:4, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: I was expecting to iterate over the number of threads, so each thread uses the print statement. So, it should have printed `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` representing each thread inside the loop.